# Converting timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, timestamp

I'm working with an external vendor that is performing an HTTP GET to my server to submit delivery reports. All is working except I can't convert the timestamp into my local format. The timestamps are submitted like this:

```
Mon, 15 Aug 2005 15:51:01 +0000
```

I then need to convert to a different format in my local timezone. This is my current code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$ts = $_GET['skebby_date_time'];
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d M y H:i:s O', $ts);
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("Australia/Sydney"));
$fmTimestamp = $date->format('m/d/Y h:i:s A');
```

This is currently generating a Fatal error: Call to a member function setTimeZone() on a non-object for this line:

```
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("Australia/Sydney"));
```

I've used similar code for other timestamps so not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`->setTimeZone()` method failed because `$date` isn't a valid `DateTime` object.

It failed to be a valid `DateTime` object because of the format you've setup.

In your current format given, its small `y` which corresponds to two digit representation:

```
Mon, 15 Aug 2005 15:51:01 +0000
D,   d  M   y    H:i:s    O
```

But you have given `2005` which corresponds to big `Y` (4 digits), so it should be:

```
D, d M Y H:i:s O
```

[Out](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xDaLNB)